# QDir::rename : redundant parameters?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using QT 5.7, and from the [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#rename):

```
bool QDir::rename(const QString &oldName, const QString &newName)
```

why should I specify the oldName of the dir? Isn't it the current name?
I'm thinking about this overloaded function:

```
bool QDir::rename(const QString &newName){
    return this->rename(this->dirName(), newName);
}
```

Is the API referred to a sub-directory of the current directory?

Comment: I haven't used it. But as I understand it, the rename applies for all elements inside that dir. Not the dir itself. would also make sense from the interface point of view then. Like QFile does not have such a rename function.

Comment: If you're trying to rename the directory *itself*, not files or directories inside of it, then use `QFile::rename`.

Comment: @peppe: from what is written in the accepted answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39229957/3253359), QFile::rename seems not to be enough. If so, a "real" QDir::rename should be added to the QT API

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `QDir::rename` doesn't rename the directory itself, it renames an element in the directory. The first argument selects the element to rename.

To rename a directory entry given by an absolute path, use the static `QFile::rename(const QString &oldName, const QString &newName)`.

To rename the directory itself you'd want something like:

```
bool renameDir(QDir & dir, const QString & newName) {
  auto src = QDir::cleanPath(dir.filePath("."));
  auto dst = QDir::cleanPath(
    dir.filePath(QStringLiteral("..%1%2").arg(QDir::separator()).arg(newName)));
  auto rc = QFile::rename(src, dst);
  if (rc) dir.setPath(dst);
  return rc;
}
```

Comment: I think that your function _renameDir_ should be part of the QDir API

Comment: @ABCplus If you truly think so, you should set up a Qt account, check out a copy of Qt, and submit a change for review :)

Answer (score 5):

No it's not redundant. A `QDir` may specify a directory in which **multiple** files may exist. For example consider the directory `"mydir/"` in which we've got files `a.txt` and `b.txt`. So using the following code snippet we can rename them based on their old name.

```
QDir dir("mydir");
dir.rename("a.txt", "aa.txt");
dir.rename("b.txt", "bb.txt");
```

Comment: The doc should be improved for sure: "Renames a file or directory _contained in the current directory object_ from oldName to newName, and returns...."